# Return whole record set if no parameter were provided

Tags: sql, where-clause, sap-ase

I am making a stored procedure that would accept ID as a parameter and will bring one record related to the ID provided and if no ID were provided bring the whole result set back.

I have managed to make some workaround with COALESCE function but I really would like to have that input parameter as INTEGER data type.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetThis
@ID VARCHAR(25) =   NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET @ID= COALESCE( @ID, '%' ) 
...

SELECT * FROM #TABLE
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),ID) LIKE @ID
END
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `OR @ID IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `OR` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM #TABLE
WHERE  @ID IS NULL
OR     CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),ID) LIKE @ID
```